# mariaDB: column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, syntax, mariadb

I don't get what's the problem here. I want to build a web scraper that scrapes amazon and takes the price and the name into a database. But for some reason, it tells me that the columns and values are not matching. I do have one additional column in my database called "timestamp" where I automatically put in the time, but that is handled by the database. I am using MariaDB. A friend said I can use the MySQL API for MariaDB as well.

P.S. preis = price, coming from Germany, switching between English and German sometimes, just in case anyone is wondering.

```py
import requests, time, csv, pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#URL = input("URL")
URL = "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B075FTXF15/ref=crt_ewc_img_bw_3?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A24FLB4J0NZBNT"
def SOUPIT (tempURL):
    URL = tempURL
    page = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
    soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")

    raw_price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    price = raw_price[:-2]


    raw_name = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    name = raw_name.strip()

    for i in range(0,len(name)-1):
        if name[i] == "(":
            name = name[:i]
            break
    data = [name, price, time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")]

    return(data)

data = SOUPIT(URL)

while True:

    data = SOUPIT(URL)

    db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    if (data == None):
        break
        print("break")
    else:
        name = data[0]
        preis = data[1]
        sql = """INSERT INTO amazon_preise (Name, Preis) VALUES ('{}',{})""".format(name,preis)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        print("success")

    print(data)
    time.sleep(60)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amazonscraper_advanced.py", line 43, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused, at least partially, by a using string formatting to insert values into an SQL statement.

Here is the scraped data:

```
>>> data = ['Sweatshirt Alien VS. Predator Z100088', '32,99', '14:08:43', '08.09.2019']
>>> name, preis, *_ = data
```

Let's create the SQL statement

```
>>> sql = """INSERT INTO amazon_preise (Name, Preis) VALUES ('{}',{})""".format(name,preis)
```

And display it:

```
>>> sql
"INSERT INTO amazon_preise (Name, Preis) VALUES ('Sweatshirt Alien VS. Predator Z100088',32,99)"
```

Observe that the `VALUES` clause contains *three* comma-separated values; this is because the web page displays currency in the German style, that is with commas separating the cents from the euros.  When interpolated into the SQL statement 
`preis` becomes two values instead of one.

The right way to fix this would be to convert `preis` from a string to a float or decimal, and use parameter substitution instead of string formatting to interpolate the values..

```
>>> fpreis = float(preis.replace(',', '.'))
>>> sql = """INSERT INTO amazon_preise (Name, Preis) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
>>> cursor.execute(sql, (name, fpreis))
```

Comment: Works. Much appreciated! Never saw that coming, tbh.